# como subir a produccion un proyecto de next.js

Tags: reactjs

//Hola gente, quiero subir a produccion mi app echa con next.js, corri el comando `next build` pense que me iba a generar una carpeta lista para subir a produccion, pero esta no lo genero, despues de que ejecute dicho comando la consola me devolvio esto

```
> next-material-kit@1.1.0 build C:\Users\enzo_\OneDrive\Escritorio\website\nextjs-material-kit
> next build

Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run the following command: `npm update`
Warning: Built-in CSS support is being disabled due to custom CSS configuration being detected.
See here for more info: https://err.sh/next.js/built-in-css-disabled

Creating an optimized production build

Compiled successfully.

Warning: You have opted-out of Automatic Static Optimization due to `getInitialProps` in `pages/_app`. This does not opt-out pages with `getStaticProps`
Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/opt-out-auto-static-optimization

Automatically optimizing pages

Page                                                           Size     First Load JS
┌ λ /                                                          644 B           150 kB
├   /_app                                                      4.51 kB        83.4 kB
├ λ /404                                                       902 B          84.3 kB
├ λ /components                                                140 kB          290 kB
├ λ /landing                                                   2.71 kB         152 kB
├ λ /login                                                     2.34 kB         150 kB
└ λ /profile                                                   2.93 kB         145 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all                                  83.4 kB
  ├ static/pages/_app.js                                       4.51 kB
  ├ chunks/b2fd4e18122dad509df474ea4384f512261c1b3e.4377d2.js  21 kB
  ├ chunks/commons.ea8649.js                                   10.7 kB
  ├ chunks/framework.619a4f.js                                 40.3 kB
  ├ chunks/styles.50ce8f.js                                    89 B
  ├ runtime/main.f9d622.js                                     6 kB
  ├ runtime/webpack.83bd83.js                                  746 B
  └ css/styles.bdb9c728.chunk.css                              4.94 kB

λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
●  (SSG)     automatically generated as static HTML + JSON (uses getStaticProps)
```

como dije anteriormente, esperaba una carpeta lista para llevar a produccion pero no la genero, no se bien que es lo que tengo que subir, me ayudan por favor

Comment: Tienes un custom server de next js?

Answer (score 1):

Depende de la implementación de tu aplicación o servicio. Lo que has generado con el comando `build` es una compilación del proyecto para producción, ahora podrías correr el comando `start` y levantar con `node` tu fichero de entrada.

Si tu aplicación sirve únicamente estáticos y quieres exportarlos, para servirlos directamente con nginx, apache u otro servidor web, tendrías que ejecutar además de `build`, `next export`, éste te generará los archivos que esperas dentro de una carpeta llamada `out`.

Siempre y cuando no estés usando `getInitialProps` ya que éste desactiva la Optimización Automática de Estáticos.
Tienes algo más de info aquí, pero en inglés:

- https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps.
- https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export